# How to get MD5 hash for file in C++

Tags: c++, linux, md5sum

I need to find duplicate files in directory but don't know how to get md5sum for file..

How to get MD5 hash for file by its path in C++ ?

Comment: OpenSSL contains components for hashing data bytes: https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/md5.html

Comment: Start by [searching](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+md5+hash&oq=c%2B%2B+md&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.5593j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)?

Answer (score 1):

The `md5sum` tool come from [coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/) use `md5_stream()` from [Gnulib](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/) to compute the MD5 sum of a file, here is [the source of `md5_stream()`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=gnulib.git;a=blob_plain;f=lib/md5.c;hb=HEAD).